# Terminal command not working with Swift

Tags: swift, cocoa, terminal, swift2

I am using this code to run a terminal command. So far, this has alway worked. Now it complains about:

```
The file /Users/meee/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/nameOfXCodeProject-baelzqzfuiydshbtbifxkywekybq/Build/Products/Debug/Chrome.app does not exist.
```

When I tried to run a command with args in it, it failed. It works like a charm in Terminal. What could be the problem?

```
let strEx = "open -a /Applications/Google Chrome.app   --args argsToSet=\"MYARGS\""
strEx.runAsCommand()

extension String {
    func runAsCommand() -> String {
        let pipe = NSPipe()
        let task = NSTask()
        task.launchPath = "/bin/sh"
        task.arguments = ["-c", String(format:"%@", self)]
        task.standardOutput = pipe
        let file = pipe.fileHandleForReading
        task.launch()
        if let result = NSString(data: file.readDataToEndOfFile(), encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding) {
            return result as String
        }
        else {return "--- Unable to initialize string from file data ---"}
    }
}
```

EDIT: This is what I used now.

```
let pipe = NSPipe()
        let task = NSTask()
        task.launchPath = "/bin/sh"
        task.arguments = [ "-c", "open", "-a","/Applications/Google Chrome.app","--args","myargs=ARGS"]
        task.standardOutput = pipe
        let file = pipe.fileHandleForReading
        task.launch()
        if let result = NSString(data: file.readDataToEndOfFile(), encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding) {
            print(result as String)
        }
        else {print("--- Unable to initialize string from file data ---")}

        for argum in task.arguments!{
            print(argum)
        }
```

It just outputs for what -c, -a... are used for.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect this line:

```
task.arguments = ["-c", String(format:"%@", self)]
```

is effectively creating this command line:

```
"/bin/sh" "-c" "open -a /Applications/Google Chrome.app   --args argsToSet=\"MYARGS\""
```

when what you want is:

```
"/bin/sh" "-c" "open" "-a" "/Applications/Google Chrome.app"   "--args" "argsToSet=\"MYARGS\""
```

(or something similar).

Therefore hold the arguments as an array, rather than a single string.  Doing that means you don't need stuff like `\"`; in fact you don't need to use quotes at all.

Comment: Thans for stopping by. I'm having little luck with the arguments array. This is how it looks:         task.arguments = [ "-c", "open", "-a","/Applications/Google Chrome.app","--args","myargs=ARGS"]. Nothing is happening, and I am not sure why.